# Hide parent term and show only second level

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm getting frustrated figuring this out for a couple of hours. I was not able to make work what I've wanted to achieve.

I have taxonomy which has sub-child. Here is my taxonomy structure:

- Parent 1

  - Child 1
  - Child 2
- Parent 2

  - Child 1
  - Child 2

When the parent term is visited, then it will list its sub-child. Like below:-

Parent 1 title

- Child 1
- Child 2

I've created a views taxonomy terms, I don't want to use content  because the term will not show if that term is empty.

In contextual filters, the taxonomy id with depth and modifier is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that when you say "When the parent term is visited" you mean at the taxonomy term page at *taxonomy/term/[..]*, the view settings below will work.

```
View type : Term
Display : block
Pager : Display all items

Relationships : Taxonomy term: Parent term
> Identifier: Parent

Contextual filter : (Parent) Taxonomy term: Term ID
> Relationship : Parent
  > When the filter value is not available : Provide default value
    > Type: Taxonomy Term ID from URL
    > Load default filter from term page : checked
```

If you want the parent term to appear instead of the vocabulary name, also do:

```
  > When the filter value is available or a default is provided : Override title
    > (argument) %1
```

You can also enter a space instead of "%1" to clear it since the parent term already appears by default as page title (otherwise it will appear twice).

Finally, if you want to sort by term weight, also do:

```
Sort criteria : Taxonomy term: Weight (asc)
```

Enable the block to only display on taxonomy term pages, appearing above the main page content block.

You can also do some interesting things when you combine the [Taxonomy Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) and [Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block) modules.

Hope that helps!